# Is there a way to write to a file while it is being used by another process (a process in ring 0?)

Tags: vb.net, kernel, streamwriter, file-access

Recently, I've been trying to write to a .PAK file while it is being used by another process in ring 0. This has been a problem for quite a while and i haven't had much success. I am able to use any programming language necessary to accomplish this, but C#/VB.net is preferred. I originally wanted to use a find and replace system when editing, but I will just choose and offset to write to and such instead.

No, I can't just terminate the process then edit; the process must be running. Yes, I obviously know the process with the file handle attached.

No, I can't just run as admin because the process is established in ring 0/the kernel.

I've tried multiple methods including setting the process speed temporarily to 0 to edit then revert, and changing the FileShare and other parameters, none with any success.

One approach which I have been told a lot and which I have no experience in is creating a "Kernel Driver". I'm not sure how to go about this and I cant find much info online so if you think that's is the best method please inform me on how to get started. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Always create a temporary file (a copy of your original file). If you need to process a file within your codes, create a temp file, use the temp file and process that file. So if you need another process, there will be no problem.

Comment: In my case, the process has a file handle established and is reading/writing directly to the file, so it wouldn't make a difference if I were to just create a copy anyway. Do you have any other ideas?